# Displaying relationships (dependency connectors) of Objects on a package level (e.g. Matrix)

Tags: dependencies, enterprise-architect, connector

Situation: We have Database table objects organised in packages. A package contains multiple tables that contain information for the same topic. We model Information Flow-Connectors between the tables of different packages for which we can create a dependency matrix. What I am not able to achieve, is to create a diagram that displays the dependencies on a package level. EA has the information which table is contained in which package, but I am not able to 'extract' it into a view.

The only solution I found so far is to model the relationship in a redundant manner, once on table level and once on package level. This is quickly a source of errors and not a desired solution.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Either you package things or you create relations. Your choice. Showing package contents is what the browser is meant for.

Answer (score 0):

The below query returns packages which are related to other packages indirectly via the contained elements, in the way you've described your information model. Hopefully this puts you on the right track.

```
select distinct srcPkg.name as srcPkg, dstPkg.name as DstPkg from (((t_object
inner join t_connector on t_connector.Start_Object_ID = t_object.Object_ID)
left join t_object dstObj on t_connector.End_Object_ID = dstObj.Object_ID)
left join t_package srcPkg on srcPkg.Package_ID = t_object.Package_ID)
left join t_package dstPkg on dstPkg.Package_ID = dstObj.Package_ID
```

Comment: That's a good point, I've edited my answer with that improvement.